# Why does parameter type inference break in compose function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference, function-composition

I encountered this in my own library, so I thought I would check against the [Redux `compose` function](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/compose.ts#L24) that does the same thing. I found the same issue.

Because `redux` is considerably more popular than my library, let's only consider their code.

This is the declaration for a 3 function `compose`:

```js
type Func<T extends any[], R> = (...a: T) => R
function compose<A, B, T extends any[], R>(
  f1: (b: B) => R,
  f2: (a: A) => B,
  f3: Func<T, A>
): Func<T, R>
```

Now, let's call it:

```js
compose(
  // why is twoTimesNPlus100 unknown?
  (twoTimesNPlus100) => `${twoTimesNPlus100} monkeys`,
  (nPlus100) => nPlus100 * 2,
  (n: number) => n + 100
)
```

If we inspect the inferred types of the parameters of the functions that are passed, we see that `nPlus100` is correctly inferred to be `number`. However, type-inference breaks down for parameter `twoTimesNPlus100` and this can only be inferred as `unknown`.

So, why does this mechanism work for generic type `A`, but fail to infer the correct type for `B`? Is there a way around this?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/PTAEBMFMGMBsEMBO8AuBLA9gOwM6lmgGYqTiiGIYC2AUCKABYooAOOAXCAOZooMCuAIwB00asESl+ADwBWOCVOnBBsDIOBV4OEomA5E0YGKosMOSMJQ4AxABkAjDRQBPFpFAAxflmgAeABVQSGkSLHA8eCwXAG0AXQAaUAAlAD5QAF5QAAphPPh2UACASkz05Jo6MDzhKPAq0HomVg5uXgERE0VwGXlumRU1DS0dSD0DIxMzCytbOwAmABYaKDgkD0IfaHRsUCnzSD8AQSSAISSgkLCI0CjYxJTU7JpQcgdC7MFC09KM8oSXuR5h8CqAjr90udAYQAMyFby+QJJI6pGjFeFbJGPSr7CzPV7ZFAAdwwATQVEgOAAcgAFWD8HAOAAMTIhoAABgASADexNJ5MptPpjJZAF9QFRsABrSAuHDsgGvEAAPQA-IDslg6QzmayyqAtcLdaAAFSgeaKxrANUarCFLD8KiCMZsrCgADUoF1aKAA)

Comment: Why are the functions in the reverse order?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky That's how function composition is defined... from right-to-left.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky `compose` is usually right to left. Since `compose(f, g)(x)` corresponds to `f(g(x))`

Comment: Well, in proper forward notation it works just fine, in case anybody is interested: https://tsplay.dev/w1PB2W

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Indeed, going in the "pipe" direction, everything works out nicely. Hoping that `compose` can be massaged to do the same.

Comment: Interesting: [Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WKyaoN) extracting the middle function to a variable works. I assume TS somehow didn't have enough information about its return type. Which is weird, since it knows it's a `number * number` but maybe it's not explicit enough? Or it's a bug?

Comment: Also weird: works if the parameter in the middle function is given an explicit type: https://tsplay.dev/WJynZm

Comment: @VLAZ Interesting find. It assures me that I'm in way over my head on why this might be :)

Comment: It's a design limitation in TS, see [ms/TS#31738](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31738).  Type inference can generally flow left-to-right through function arguments, so `pipe()` is fine but `compose()` isn't.  You'll need to do some explicit type annotations or specifications in some places you "shouldn't" to get things to type check the way you want.  Does that fully address your question or am I missing something?

Comment: @spender Offtop: what are the other magical comments, such as `//^?`? Is there a list somewhere? Pretty useful stuff!

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky FWIW, I just know they are called introspection comments. But I don't know if there is a list available. I've only seen them used by other people.

Comment: @jcalz That does indeed answer the question. I'll give you the points if you answer. Many thanks.